# How to solve Json format error/issues when using curl command

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, curl

I am using Google PaLM model api to run few models using Python in Pycharm. Every time I use curl with payload, I get some sort of errors. Sometimes due to single quote, or sometime due to double quotes in my text data. How to get rid of these issues without changing my data? May be I am new to payload and curl command.

Here is the curl command that I use:

```
curl -X POST   -H "Authorization: *****"       -H "Content-Type: application/json"        https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/model:predict -d $'{ "instances": [
{"context": "\n    I want you to act as an attentive and sympathetic customer service agent.\n Given user queries, you should always refer to both the conversation history and the provided context to generate a human-like\n    response including small talks if possible. ", "messages": [{"author": "user", "content": "How to unlock Google account?"}, {"author": "bot", "content": "There are a few reasons why your Google account might be locked. If you've forgotten your password, you can reset it by following the instructions on the Google website. If you've entered your password incorrectly too many times, your account may be temporarily locked for security reasons. In this case, you'll need to wait a few hours before trying to log in again. If your account has been locked for a more serious reason, such as suspicious activity, you'll need to contact Google customer support for help.\r\n\r\nTo unlock your Google account, you can follow these steps:\r\n\r\n1. Go to the Google website and sign in.\r\n2. If you're unable to sign in, click on the \"Forgot your password?\" link.\r\n3. Enter your email address or mobile phone number and click on the \"Submit\" button.\r\n4. You'll receive an email or text message with a link to reset your"}, {"author": "user", "content": "Thank you!"}]}], "parameters": {"temperature": 0.0,"maxDecodeSteps": 200,"topP": 0.8,"topK": 1  }}'
```

In the above curl I get the error `"Invalid JSON payload received. Closing quote expected in string.\n\n^",`

I put my text data inside `instances` which is list of dictionary.

I pass curl in this way:

```
curl = """curl \
       -X POST \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer %s"\
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%s/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/%s:predict -d \
       $'{ "instances": %s, "parameters": {"temperature": 0.0,"maxDecodeSteps": 200,"topP": 0.8,"topK": 1  }}'
     """%(token ,proj,model,json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii=True))

subprocess.Popen(curl, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

d is the data that I pass. Example:

```
d=[
    {"context":  """
    I want you to act as an attentive and sympathetic customer service agent for Google.
        1) you should use the context as the only source of truth and DO NOT make up answers on your own. \
        """,
  
    "messages": [{"author": "user","content": "How to unlock Google account?",}
                ],
    }
]
```

Sometimes I need to remove single quote from my data, `like you'll to youll` to make it work. Is there other way which I can use so that I do not have to modify my data.

In the above case when I removed single quote by `replace command` it was working.

```
resp.replace("'","")
resp.replace('"',"")
```

Fails for this curl also

```
curl        -X POST        -H "Authorization: ****"       -H "Content-Type: application/json"        https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/google/models -d        $'''{ "instances": [{"context": "\n    I want you to act as an attentive and sympathetic customer service agent for Google.\n    , "messages": [{"author": "user", "content": "How to unlock Google account?"}, {"author": "bot", "content": "There are a few reasons why your Google account might be locked. Here are some of the most common reasons and how to unlock your account:\n\n* **You entered your password incorrectly too many times.** If you enter your password incorrectly three times, your account will be locked for 30 minutes. To unlock your account, you'll need to enter your email address and password again.\n* **:\n\n1. ."}, {"author": "user", "content": "Coul'd you please repeat the steps.?"}]}], "parameters": {"temperature": 0.0,"maxDecodeSteps": 400,"topP": 0.7,"topK": 1  }}'''
```

Comment: Use a triple quoted string `curl -X POST   -H "Authorization: *****"       -H "Content-Type: application/json"        https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/model:predict -d $'''{ "instances": [  ... 1  }}'''`

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)